# In testNG, running in parallel, can you share state within a test run? i.e Create Account in beforeMethod and get the account in the test?

Tags: java, testng

I'm trying to run my test suite in parallel, and this requires that accounts be created for each test. I have a test class that defines many tests, and since testNG doesn't use a separate instance of my test class for each run, I'm not guaranteed to get a separate, unique account for each test. I could use a ThreadLocal variable, but this seems like an ugly solution that doesn't quite match my desired 'TestLocal' requirement. I also seem to not have a guarantee that my @BeforeMethod will run in the same thread as my @Test, which throws this off.

This use case seems basic enough that I'm surprised about the lack of information provided for it, so is my entire approach to this wrong? There are many questions around sharing state *between* tests but not so many about sharing the state *within* a test.

As a simple example, I want to do something like:

```
private Account a;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
   a = createAccountExternalCall();
}

@Test
public void test1() {
   a.setField1("Hello");
   assertEquals("Hello", a.getField1())
}

@Test
public void test2() {
   a.setField1("Goodbye");
   assertEquals("GoodBye", a.getField1())
}
```

Running in parallel, these tests are not guaranteed to pass since the assertion in test1 may run after the setup() method in the @BeforeMethod for test2, or even after the setField1 method is completed in test2. However if I could guarantee that the accounts were different for each test, I could assert accurately.

Comment: Could you share a sample of what you want to do? About `@BeforeMethod` method, it is supposed to be invoked in the same thread than `Test` method. But there are some already known issues about it (check http://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues)

Comment: I'll update the post with some examples of what I'm trying to do, but if what you say is true and the fact that the BeforeMethod and Test methods running on separate threads is not as designed, then I'm happy to use a ThreadLocal variable - I thought that it was specifically not guaranteed to be true.

Comment: @RankWeis - ThreadLocal should work for you in this case. BeforeMethod -> Test -> AfterMethod will always run in the same thread. So the states can always be shared between a Test and BeforeMethod/AfterMethod.